# Access class this from each in a jQuery plugin widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to access the this.options variable from within a each loop.
I am using the jQuery ui Widget Factory pattern.

```
// etc..
,
_buildThumbs: function() {

$.each(this.options.photos, function( i, photo ) {

    // Modify template html...
    // ...


    $(this.options.containerThumbsClass).append( thumbnail );
    // Oh my, this.options is undefined :(
});
```

So what is the best way to access the options? Maybe pass the class reference to the each method? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That's because jquery 'each' function has it's own context. Try this:

```
_buildThumbs: function() {
var localOptionsVariable = this.options;
$.each(this.options.photos, function( i, photo ) {    
    $(localOptionsVariable.containerThumbsClass).append( thumbnail );
});
```

But the best way is to have a function within your plugin that will return options object. For instance, you can store options in the root element [data](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

[Edited]

```js
(function ($) {
    var PLUGIN_NAMESPACE = "your-plugin-namespace";
    var defaultOptions = {
        someOption: 'DefaultOptionValue'
    };
    var isIE = /msie/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

    $.extend($.fn, {
        setTestPlugin: function (options) {
            options = $.extend({}, defaultOptions, options);
            return this.each(function () {
                var $container = $(this);
                $container.addClass(PLUGIN_NAMESPACE);
                $container.data("options", options);

                $container.val('Plugin applied!')
                $container.on('click', function(){
                  $container.someOtherFunction();
                });
            });
        },
        getOptions: function () {
            return this.data("options");
        },
        someOtherFunction: function () {
            var $container = this;
            var options = $container.getOptions();
            $.each([0], function(i, item){
              alert(options.someOption);
            });
            
        },
    });

})(jQuery);

$('#textBoxNewOption').setTestPlugin({someOption: 'New option value'});
$('#textBoxDefault').setTestPlugin();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textBoxDefault" />
<input type="text" id="textBoxNewOption" />
```

Comment: `this` within the `$.each` callback will be the same as the second argument `photo`. The second line is wrong: using `.data` is good advice in general but not in this case -- you'd still need access to `this.element`. A common way to keep `this` in inner callbacks is by using `$.proxy` (or `call`/`bind` if you're more comfortable with them)

Comment: @blgt, I prefer time-honoured 'call', and I usually have $container variable within each plugin function so I can execute something like '$container.getOptions()' with proper context. Is there any alternative except that you have already mentioned?

Comment: Several - depending on where you store the options; it's a matter of personal preference, none of the alternatives offer any substantial usability improvement over the others like using a `$container`. It's just using `.data()` that unnecessarily complicates it

Comment: Hi Ivan. Can you please provide an example of the best solution? I can't follow this discussion. Btw, this.options is just an example. I mean accessing the class var this within functions like each. Passing the class reference. Or accessing it on a nice way.

Comment: @Floris, as you probably noticed there is no 'best solution' but several suitable. See edited answer